# JS Ray Tracer object infinitely long

Tags: javascript, raytracing, renderer

I have written a very primitive ray tracer in JS, it renders only one cube by shooting one ray from each pixel and checking if it intersects with the cube. If it intersects then that pixel is set to white and if not, black.

However the object starts in the correct place but is not the correct dimensions. This is best explained with a picture:

[image: raytracing attempt with one cube]

I have posted the code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mp3bzr7k/4/) **However if you run it, it will take a very long time** if you want to speed it up then reduce the number of iterations in

```
function main_v
```

I think the problem is with the ray intersection test (intersect_b function) however I have been unable to track down the problem. The intersection function is directly adapted from [here](http://www.scratchapixel.com/lessons/3d-basic-lessons/lesson-7-intersecting-simple-shapes/ray-box-intersection/)

Comment: Just FYI your fiddle gives `Uncaught ReferenceError: main_v is not defined` when I click the button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One issue is this:

```js
function c2p_p(r) {
    return r.type == vType.Cartesian ? {
        r: Math.sqrt(r.x ^ 2 + r.y ^ 2 + r.z ^ 2),
        theta: Math.acos(r.z / Math.sqrt(r.x ^ 2 + r.y ^ 2 + r.z ^ 2)),
        phi: Math.atan2(r.y / r.x),
        type: vType.Polar
    } : r
}
```

In JavaScript, the `^` operator is bitwise XOR, not exponentiation.  Just write `r.x*r.x + r.y*r.y + r.z*r.z` instead.